# jquery datepicker dont run one one4 page, on another it does

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can t find the cause: On this and the other pages, the script run: http://www.ruhrlink.de/termine.php
But on this not: http://www.ruhrlink.de/cgi/terminsuchen.php

The script is used from a same PHP Script (functions.php), so it normally should run.

I am no JS programmer. Searched for hours.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

I have fond it by myself. terminsuchen is situated in a subdirectory and there the root for the scripts would be CGI, not root. Simple but the same is in PHP. Saturday morning ;-)